# Why a local image (304 not modified) takes 4.28 seconds to render?

Tags: html, dom, web, firebug

Can someone please explain why an image being loaded from my local machine is taking 4.28 seconds to render?

[image: Firefox Network Log]

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is it happening at each load of the page?

Comment: not consistently and not the same image... but our rendering is taking too long even when the base page is loaded quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a 304 HTTP status code doesn't mean there is no request to the server. It means that the server responded there was no change to the document since the last time it was fetched, which results in the contents being fetched from the browser cache.

This is also reflected in the HTTP headers displayed for the request:
[image: HTTP headers for cached file in Firebug's *Net* panel]

Your screenshot indicates by the bar at the ['Waiting' state](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Request_Timeline), that the server takes 4.28s to respond to this request.

So it looks like your problem relates to a misconfiguration of your server. Therefore you should check your server logs and settings for what's causing this delay.

Comment: duh... should have thought of that. It makes sense that its waiting for server to respond with a 304